# Linear Independence with distinct variables

Tags: linear-algebra

If there is a group of vectors $v$ such that

$v=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\1
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\x_2
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2\\x_2^2
\end{array}\right)$

where $x_1\neq x_2,$ is $v$ linearly independent? If so, why?

**Edit**

Thank you! So what if

$v=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\1
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2\\x_2^2\\x_3^2
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1^3\\x_2^3\\x_3^3
\end{array}\right)?$

(where $x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3$)

Comment: Not if $ x_1 = 1$ and $ x_2 = -1 $

Comment: $3$ vectors with $2$ entries can never be linearly independent.  Same goes for $4$ vectors with $3$ entries.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why?

Comment: Rigorously speaking, it's a consequence of the [dimension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm sorry. I don't understand :( Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is depend on x1 and x2 for example x1=0,x2=1 so v is dependent.